# Understanding the Tar command to archive & compress the file on the remote server

Tags: ssh, tar, cat

```
tar zcf - source-file | ssh root@remote-server-IP "cat > remote-server-location.tar.gz"
```

The command is perfect , but I want to understand the command.

I got the part where it pipes the output to ssh, but why is cat command used for?

Can anyone help me understand?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `cat` is used to grab the information which is sent via ssh and redirect it to file on remote system. You just can't do it on this way:

```
tar zcf - source-file | ssh root@remote-server-IP "> remote-server-location.tar.gz"
```

because this will only create empty `remote-server-location.tar.gz` file.

If you try without quotes:

```
tar zcf - source-file | ssh root@remote-server-IP > remote-server-location.tar.gz
```

this will create the file on local filesystem